# Linear Programming - Modelling Objective Function to Include Revenue as well as Cost

Tags: logic, linear-programming

I am new to Linear Programming.
The general two-variable problems I see have the objective function as maximizing profit.

However, what if there is a cost per unit of each variable?

Example: I have two resources A and B, that are both used in different amounts to produce X and Y, and I make \$5 for each X and \$9 for each Y.
But each time unit of A takes \$2 and B takes \$1.
Also, there are 10 time units each available of A and B.

My doubt is that, is my objective function simply

> Max : P = 5X + 9Y

or is it some function that takes into account the cost of resources A and B spent?

For example,

> Max: P = 3X + 7.5Y    (Assuming X costs \$2 and Y costs \$1.5

Comment: Do you know how many units of A and B you need to produce one unit of X and/or Y? Right now you're using every variable as if they were of the same kind, but they're not. If you know how to relate them you can write a new function just considering one kind of variables.